# Can't launch multiple scripts on the same browser session?

Tags: php, apache, firefox, debian

Today is THE day I didn't find the answer I'm looking  on the web (it never happened before). The fact is, I didn't find how to question google.

My problem : I run a PHP script "X" on my server (who need several hours) and I can't go to another page "Y" on the same server with Firefox.

But if I load page "Y" with Chrome, it works. How can I setup my server to launch several scripts (on the same server) with the same browser ?

Comment: Which web server are you using? Apache, Nginx, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you use sessions: When you run a script that uses a session, the session is locked. As the same browser is trying to access the same session, it will not work; the browser will have to wait until the session by the other tab / browser window is closed.

Possible solutions are for example:

- Close the session as soon as possible / when you don't need it any more;
- Don't use sessions for the long-running scripts;
- Use different browsers / incognito mode so that the session information is not shared.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. 
I had to release the session lock in the scripts with "session_write_close() "and now it work. 
Thanks for helping!